# System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oledb

I am getting the following error while trying to read from an excel file in my server.

**"System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."**

The code runs smoothly in localhost, but the error comes when i host it online.

I am unable to post the stacktrace as i do not get error everytime, but the executions stops at the line **"objConn.open"**. The page just says loading... and nothing happens.

**Here is my code block :**

```
     fuGroupAttributes.SaveAs(IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Admin/SpecificationExcels"), lblParentId.Text.Trim & IO.Path.GetExtension(fuGroupAttributes.FileName)))
'saving the excel file from the fileUploader

                           Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/Admin/SpecificationExcels/" & lblParentId.Text.Trim & IO.Path.GetExtension(fuGroupAttributes.FileName))
'getting the file path from the server


                           Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
                           Dim objConn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
                           **objConn.Open()** 'this is where i am getting the error.
                           Dim strConString As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
```

EDIT : The page keeps saying loading ... it wont stop loading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probable reason is, your user account on the machine does not have sufficient access to perform this operation. On localhost, you might be using the Administrator account and it is not so in the live machine.

Comment: You are talking about rights to access the file system. I am sure you definitely have that because if you didn't you might be getting error of a different kind, (File access exception). What I am trying to say is, you either do not have permission to use the oledb driver for excel. There are several reasons for that, one of which is - on generally shared web servers, your web application do not run in "Full trust environment" - i suggest you search this term on google and you will find some useful hints

Comment: i tried by changing my connection string to `Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""` and now i get this error `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.`

Comment: As you are able to open the file locally, it is absolutely no problem with the connection string or the code. The problem is with the identity which your web server(IIS) is impersonating. If possible, try executing the same code on another web server.

Comment: sorry i do not have any other web server...the file is opening properly in my local machine...the code works smoothly locally.

Comment: oh, I think I might got it, pls check if your file is readonly after you have uploaded it. If it is so, you will get this error

Comment: you mean ...i should download the file and check it??

Comment: No, check it on the server itself, if it is readonly or not. Try uploading the file from FTP and set the permission to 777 using ftp client itself.(Most of the ftp clients does have this feature) and let me know if it resolves the issue or not.

Comment: what i have observed is the excel file is getting locked somehow when the it is uploaded, it gets the locked file and thus throws this error.

Comment: I have manually uploaded the excel file, hardcoded the path and the code works fine... can anybody suggest what could be happening here ?