# Convert From .xls to .pdf with EO.Pdf

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

When I try to convert small `.xls` files (30-200 kb), everything is ok, but when I try to convert large `.xls` files (50 mb), I have a problem.

This is my code:

```
string filePathDoc = "C:\\Users\\vgocov\\Desktop\\testPDF\\freelimits_20140107.xls"; 
string filePathPdf = "C:\\Users\\vgocov\\Desktop\\testPDF\\freelimits_20140107.pdf";

HtmlToPdfOptions options = new HtmlToPdfOptions();
options.PageSize = EO.Pdf.PdfPageSizes.A4;

HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtml(File.ReadAllText(filePathDoc, filePathPdf, options);
```

And exception is:

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason might be because your user account on the machine does not have sufficient access to perform this operation or maybe the file is set to ReadOnly. On localhost, you might be using the Administrator account and it is not so in in a production/live server.

Check the below links and see if any might help you:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8789ea67-fbc5-4a7b-a4eb-d4a8a050d5c1/attempt-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indicating-that-other-memory-is-corrupt

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f48c152-68cd-45ec-a11e-baa7de7f79c3/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory?forum=csharpgeneral

[System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651684/system-accessviolationexception-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory)

Comment: Thanks for replay.
I try with this. Yes there was improvement with .xls (4 mb) but with .xls (10 mb) i get this exception:
 Convertion failed. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Comment: Then it's has to do with memory. Check your code & Debug properly to know where your app is consuming so much memory.

Comment: Ok thanks but there is my cod. and i can not debug HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtml becouse is dll. Is it possible problem with liberaly EO or is it impossible to convert so large file.